# Hive - error while using dynamic partition query

Tags: hadoop, hive, derby

I am trying to execute the query below:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE nasdaq_daily
  PARTITION(stock_char_group)
  select exchage, stock_symbol, date, stock_price_open,
         stock_price_high, stock_price_low, stock_price_close,
         stock_volue, stock_price_adj_close,
         SUBSTRING(stock_symbol,1,1) as stock_char_group
  FROM nasdaq_daily_stg;
```

I have already set `hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true` and `hive.exec.dynamic.partiion.mode=nonstrict;`.

Table `nasdaq_daily_stg` table contains proper information in the form of a number of CSV files. When I execute this query, I get this error message:

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.authentication is sealed.

FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask

The `mapreduce` job didnt start at all. So there are no logs present in the `jobtracker` web-UI for this error. I am using derby to store meta-store information.

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: You may want to look at the permissions and owner of the directory where the `mapreduce` jars are present and the user who's running the `Hive` jobs.I believe it the Hive job should be run from the `hdfs` user.

Comment: I am able to execute other mapreduce and hive queries. So, this might not be related to permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. This may be the issue. You may be having Derby classes twice on your classpath.

["SecurityException: sealing violation" when starting Derby connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454061/securityexception-sealing-violation-when-starting-derby-connection)