# Error java : java.lang.SecurityException : sealing vioaltion : package org.apache.derby.iapi.types is sealed , Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-1"

Tags: java

Im tring to excute a java code to do a copy and have backup of my BO server.
I excute the java code from a batch via windows power shell, the connection for the system works very well, the folders are created in the mentioned directory but they still empty, and i have the errors message below

Can anybody helps me to understand those errors ?
Thank you :)

Error1:
java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package org.apache.derby.iapi.types is sealed
at java.net.URLClassLoader.getAndVerifyPackage(URLClassLoader.java:467)

Error2:
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/busine ssobjects/sdk/biar/internal/db/Derby : cannot initialize class because prior ini tialization attempt failed at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.om.internal.db.AnnotatedObjectDatabase.< init>(AnnotatedObjectDatabase.java:23) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.om.internal.db.AnnotatedObjectDatabase.g etInstance(AnnotatedObjectDatabase.java:50)
at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.om.internal.ObjectManager.(ObjectM anager.java:97) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.BIARFactory.createOM(BIARFactory.java:10 1) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.BIARFactory.createOM(BIARFactory.java:85 ) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.BIARFactory.createOM(BIARFactory.java:75 ) at com.businessobjects.lcm.dependencies.DependencyManager.calculateDepen denciesUsingDM(DependencyManager.java:702) at com.businessobjects.lcm.dependencies.DependencyManager.computeDepende es(DependencyManager.java:683) at com.businessobjects.lcm.core.LCMEngine.computeDependees(LCMEngine.jav a:1237) at com.businessobjects.lcm.job.Job$1.run(Job.java:1308) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor. java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor .java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializ erError at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forNameFW(Class.java:362) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.internal.db.Derby.(Derby.java:49 ) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.om.internal.db.AnnotatedObjectDatabase.< init>(AnnotatedObjectDatabase.java:23) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.om.internal.db.AnnotatedObjectDatabase.g etInstance(AnnotatedObjectDatabase.java:50) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.om.internal.ObjectManager.(ObjectM anager.java:97) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.BIARFactory.createOM(BIARFactory.java:10 1) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.BIARFactory.createOM(BIARFactory.java:85 ) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.BIARFactory.createOM(BIARFactory.java:75 ) at com.businessobjects.lcm.dependencies.DependencyManager.calculateDepen denciesUsingDM(DependencyManager.java:702) at com.businessobjects.lcm.dependencies.DependencyManager.computeDepende es(DependencyManager.java:683) at com.businessobjects.lcm.core.LCMEngine.computeDependees(LCMEngine.jav a:1237) at com.businessobjects.lcm.job.Job$1.run(Job.java:1308) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor. java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor .java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package org.apache.de rby.iapi.types is sealed at java.net.URLClassLoader.getAndVerifyPackage(URLClassLoader.java:467) at java.net.URLClassLoader.definePackageInternal(URLClassLoader.java:487 ) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:519) at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:76) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:431) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:425) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:424) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:480) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:384) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:413) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forNameFW(Class.java:362) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.getImplementations (Unknown Source) at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.getDefaultImplemen tations(Unknown Source) at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.runWithState(Unkno wn Source) at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.(Unknown Sou rce) at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startMonitor(Unknown S ource) at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(Unknown Source) at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(Unknown Source) at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.boot(Unknown Source) at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forNameFW(Class.java:362) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.internal.db.Derby.(Derby.java:49 ) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.om.internal.db.AnnotatedObjectDatabase.< init>(AnnotatedObjectDatabase.java:23) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.om.internal.db.AnnotatedObjectDatabase.g etInstance(AnnotatedObjectDatabase.java:50) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.om.internal.ObjectManager.(ObjectM anager.java:97) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.BIARFactory.createOM(BIARFactory.java:10 1) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.BIARFactory.createOM(BIARFactory.java:85 ) at com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.BIARFactory.createOM(BIARFactory.java:75 ) at com.businessobjects.lcm.dependencies.DependencyManager.calculateDepen denciesUsingDM(DependencyManager.java:702) at com.businessobjects.lcm.dependencies.DependencyManager.computeDepende es(DependencyManager.java:683) at com.businessobjects.lcm.core.LCMEngine.computeDependees(LCMEngine.jav a:1237) at com.businessobjects.lcm.job.Job$1.run(Job.java:1308) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor. java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor .java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) at java.lang.Class.setExceptionThrownDuringClinit(Class.java:3686) ... 13 more.

Comment: please post your information as formatted text, not a link to an image

Comment: here is your likely culprit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454061/securityexception-sealing-violation-when-starting-derby-connection